# How to change MUI v6 DatePicker text field to standard variant

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-date-picker

My current code

```
 <DatePicker
              label="End Day"
              inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
              value={activityEndTime}
              onChange={updateEndTime}
              sx={{
                width: "10rem",
              }}
            />
```

here is how it looks like

[image]

how i want it to look like (i just want an underline, not a full rectangle outline)

[image]

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired result can achieved by adding a `slotProps` property:

```
<DatePicker
              label="End Day"
              inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
              value={activityEndTime}
              onChange={updateEndTime}
              sx={{
                width: "10rem",
              }}
              slotProps={{ textField: { variant: "standard" } }}
 />
```